# Generate a sequence in Python for barcoding items

Tags: python

I am trying to generate barcodes in an app to tag the products which includes 3 things:

1. Batch no. (GRN ID)
2. Product ID
3. serial ID

Something like this:

```
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        grn = Grn.objects.filter(pk=pk)[0]
        grn_prod = grn.items.all()
        items = []
        for i in grn_prod:
            for j in range(i.item_quantity):
                items.append("YNT" + str(pk) + str(i.item.pk) + str(j + 1))
```

It generates a sequence like the following:

`YNT55232`

Which is good but while scanning it if I want to know the `item ID` or `Serial ID` the it becomes a problem as it could be 23, 523, 3, etc.

For this I want to specify a no of digits for `GRN`, `Product` and `Serial Id` something like this:

```
GRN Barcode     GRN ID  Product ID  Serial ID
            YNT  000X     000X       0000X
```

I am unable to figure out how to append `0` before the `IDs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) function does exactly this.
`str.zfill(5)` will pad given string in variable `str` to at least 5 characters, for example.

Comment: Your answer is concise and helping ️. Hope you don't mind, that I formatted the link ?! ️ What about adding a solving code-snippet showing the use of _zfill_ like: `"YNT" + str(pk).zfill(4) + str(i.item.pk).zfill(4) + str(j + 1).zfill(5)` ❔️

Answer (score 2):

you can use `format` in Python. It is commonly used to format many variables.

If you want to format this: `"YNT" + str(pk) + str(i.item.pk) + str(j + 1)`
you can use `format` as below:

```
'"YNT"\t{:04d}\t{:04d}\t{:05d}'.format(pk, i.item.pk, j+1)
```

In case you do not know; the `{}` are for each variable as in order in `format()`.

As you want to have `pk` and `i.item.pk` as four characters, then you add `:04d`. `:04d` completes the words with 0. For instance;

if `pk = 1`, then it converts it to `0001`, or if it is `101` then it converts to `0101`.

Same is for `j+1`, if `j+1` is 1, then it generates `00001`, if it is `101`, then it generates `00101`.

If you have not used format in Python, I suggest you learn it. It is really helpful for formatting variables.

Comment: And mention the `\t` between the padded numbers which. It adds the _tab_ character to have some horizontal spacing between the number-blocks. So `YNT55232` wont never be the result. If you like to have a continuous number after prefix "YNT" you have to leave the `\t` out.

Comment: This is good but zfill() also does this neatly

Comment: @RahulSharma Thus `zfill()` for string-padding was proposed by Venkat's answer. This answer here, also fulfills sting-padding and moreover suggests a neat solution to show the __structure of the barcode__ in one format-literal. IMO the suggested code-line is very readable and illustrates the _generated barcode_  at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve [String formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).

### %-formatting

Look at the above mention documentation of string function `zfill`. A box follows that explains:

[printf style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) using the `%` operator (modulo):

```py
barcode = '%(gnr)03d%(product)03d%(serial)04d' % {'gnr': 123, 'product': 456, 'serial': 7890}

print(barcode)
```

produces `YNT1234567890`.

### f-strings (since Python 3.6)

You can also use the Python 3 way with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```py
# barcode components readable named
gnr = pk
product = i.item.pk
serial = j + 1

#  format-literal simply will replace the variables named
barcode = f"YNT{gnr:03}{product:03}{serial:04}"

items.append(barcode)
```

It uses a prefix after the variable-name:

- `:0x` for left-padding with *x* leading zeros.

---

Note: I always clearly named the *template-variables* (here: barcode components):

- put in a map with descriptive keys (like above in %-formatting)
- put in separate variables with names describing each of them (like in f-string example)

So we can use a readable *template* also called *format-literal* like:
`"{component_1} before {component_2} then {the_rest}"`